# Translate activerecord attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, translate, ri

I saw a lot of topics on Stack but still can't find solution. 
I had to translate my model attribute so I followed:

[Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

I want get something like this: "Pozycja nie może być puste" <= "%{attribute}   %{message}

attribute => position
message => nie może być puste"

So I built this but it isn't working. How setup this interpolation?

```
errors:
  format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    messages:
      blank: "nie może być puste"

activerecord:
  models:
    user: 
      attributes:
        position: "Pozycja"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys hierarchy should be proper,

It should be like this

```
pl:
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
      messages:
        blank: "nie może być puste"

  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user: 
        position: "Pozycja"
```

For more you can always refer rails [en.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml)